# SKMapSurfaceView get freezed

Tags: android, skmaps

In many times I've noticed if I left the device for a long time on the mapview, when I try to use the maps again, UI gets freeze and the map view goes on black. At this point other elements from the app like, services and content providers are working properly.

Here is a logcat section that call my attention:

```
           Surface  E  dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -2147483646
     Adreno-EGLSUB  W  <DequeueBuffer:720>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
           Surface  E  dequeueBuffer: IGraphicBufferProducer::requestBuffer failed: -2147483646
     Adreno-EGLSUB  W  <DequeueBuffer:720>: dequeue native buffer fail: Unknown error 2147483646, buffer=0x0, handle=0x0
        Adreno-EGL  W  <qeglDrvAPI_eglSwapBuffers:3702>: EGL_BAD_SURFACE
    OpenGLRenderer  W  swapBuffers encountered EGL_BAD_SURFACE on 0xb9929bc8, halting rendering...
```

It's like skmaps is trying to release some resources and fails.

I have a couple of android devices, Moto's e 1st and 2nd generation running android 5.1. 
I had no opportunity to test on the skobbler demo app.

Comment: Please test in the demo app and let us know if the issue reproduce there too and in case you're using multiple maps please check the doc: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec033